# What does it mean to correct a formula?

Tags: logic, formal-languages

I apologize if this question is too imprecise. In logic textbooks, we are given certain rules for constructing well-formed formulas. For instance, $(x+y)$ is a term. Suppose the logic textbook gives us an exercise to "correct" the formula $x+y$. We would give the answer: $(x+y)$. It is the notion of correcting formulas that I want to make precise. More formally, we are given a certain string $S$, and we want to find a way to "correct" it to a certain well-formed formula $W$. This may not be possible for all strings $S$, and certain strings may have more than one correction. For an example of the latter, consider the string $x+y+z$ and its two corrections $((x+y)+z)$ and $(x+(y+z))$. So, what exactly does it mean to correct a formula? Also, has any book or paper discussed this topic?

Comment: The process of going from "human readable" notation to progressively more formal notations has certainly been studied. In computer science departments this process is called "desugaring", since the human readable versions are often called [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).  This is also studied by people who make [parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), since the end goal is to _parse_ the (possibly ambiguous) $x+y+z$ into the unambiguous $(x + (y+z))$. This is hard in general, but if your conventions are well defined (eg: associate right) it's doable

Comment: I don't have any references on hand for these topics (I learned about them "in the wild") but if you like I can flesh this out into an answer later tonight (and I can probably find references, if you want them).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, I would like an answer and some references.

Comment: Why do you think it is possible: what is the "correction" of $pq$? Either $p \land q$ or $p \lor q$ or $p \to q$ or $p \leftrightarrow q$ or $p$ or $q$ or...